# preg_match и точное совпадение

Tags: php

```
if (preg_match('/'.$q2d.'/i', $ussssrl))
```

`$q2d` - это (chocolate-spritz)

`$ussssrl` - это:

```
www.cooks.com/recipe/wt3s285h/chocolate-spritz-cookies.html
www.keyingredient.com/recipes/681141330/chocolate-spritz/
www.dominosugar.com/recipe/chocolate-spritz-cookies-272
```

как найти точное совпадение

т.е.

```
www.keyingredient.com/recipes/681141330/chocolate-spritz/

+++++++++++++++

chocolate-spritz

.../chocolate-spritz/

.../chocolate-spritz
```

Может быть после совпадения пробел или `/`

Comment: А вы критерии "точного совпадения" приведите. потому что ваша подстрока есть во всех приведенных. но вы видимо хотите ориентироваться на косые. Ну так и ищите строку с косыми чертами, только разумеется заэкранируйте их. что бы итоговое выражение оказалось `'/\/chocolate-spritz\//'`

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, используйте специальные сервисы. [Ваш пример](http://regexr.com/3cikn). В шаблон добавлен слэш или пробел после фразы.

```
/(chocolate-spritz)[ \/]/
```